# How to generate JSON from the csv file in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to construct a Json structure from the csv file. This below code gives me the error stating :- `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_json'` . I am new to python world and would like to ask for your help on this.

CSV Data Look like this:

[image]

I want output to be like below

```
[
    {"Variable": "Latitude",
    "Min": "78",
    "Q1": "89"} ,

    {"Variable": "Longitude",
    "Min": "78",
    "Q1": "89"},
    {"Variable": "Zip",
    "Min": "78",
    "Q1": "89"}
]

import pandas    
res_data = pd.read_csv("C\\Documents\\abc.csv", 'r')
abc=res_data.to_json(orient='records')
print(abc)
```

Comment: What is `res_df` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv("path_of_csv")
js = df.to_json(orient="records")
json.loads(js)
```

Output:

```
[{'variable': 'Latitude', 'min': 26.84505, 'Q1': 31.19725},
 {'variable': 'Longtitude', 'min': -122.315, 'Q1': -116.558},
 {'variable': 'Zip', 'min': 20910.0, 'Q1': 32788.5}]
```

Comment: Perfect. Simple and best

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("variable", "min", "Q1")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: It works but not generating the proper json structure. There should be comma separated for each row and the whole json should be enclosed in []

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply using `csv` module.

```
import csv
import json

output_dict = []
with open('abc.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        output_dict.append(row)

print json.dumps(output_dict)
```

output_dict will contain list of dict of include all rows. `json.dumps` will convert python `dict` to `json`.

and output will be:

```
[{'variable': 'Latitude', 'min': 26.84505, 'Q1': 31.19725},
 {'variable': 'Longtitude', 'min': -122.315, 'Q1': -116.558},
 {'variable': 'Zip', 'min': 20910.0, 'Q1': 32788.5}]
```

More details abou csv.DictReader : [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)